# PLS-00221: 'SALE_TOTAL_AMOUNT' is not a procedure or is undefined

Tags: sql, plsql

i created a function called sale_total_amount and it showed my that my function was created. now when i try to pass a parameter to do some calculations i get the error "not a procedure or is undefined"

Please find the error image here

[image: please find the error image here]

Comment: You sould at least share the code of this function (or a simplified version of it), and the code that calls it.

Comment: Please do not post pictures that cannot be read.  Edit the question, remove the picture, and enter the text including a [mcve] of the function, and the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

search for the function in the schema. You can search for that in user_procedeures or you can browse using some tool like SQL developer or toad.

My guess is that that either function does not exist or its signature (input/output type) is little different that what you are expecting

Please post output of this query:
select * from ALL_PROCEDURES where object_name = 'YOUR FUNCTION NAME';

Answer (score 2):

I think the key sentence in your question is "showed my that my function was created"

A function returns a value, your call as it is written has nowhere for that value to go, hence the "Not a procedure" (it is a function) error.

You would need something more like

```
Declare

V_variable number default null;

begin
  v_variable := sale_total_amount(1);
end;
```

This has the following assumptions

1) That it really is a function

2) That it returns a number (guessed from the name of your function)

3) That you are aware that you will not see any output, it will just complete successfully.  If you want to see output you will need to add a dbms_output.put_line(v_variable) or similar to actually display something.

Comment: This was the answer for me, was looking at the signature of the method I was calling for some time based on the chosen answer but it was a case of not saving the return value anywhere.